# Concatenating GoPro videos with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I have several GoPro recordings at 60 fps which I would like to concatenate. Is `ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_list.txt -c copy out.MP4` the right command to concatenate GoPro videos? concat_list.txt contains a list of the GoPro video files (mp4). I'm just asking because the concatenated video is 2s longer than the summation of all the individual video durations. When I run the command the ouput looks as follows (I run it on Win 7):

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000004ee340] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[concat @ 00000000004e2cc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, concat, from 'U:\GoPro_concat\concat_video.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15110 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14982 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16T13:18:14.000000Z
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16T13:18:14.000000Z
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
    Stream #0:2: Unknown: none
Output #0, mp4, to 'U:\GoPro_concat\GoPro_concat.MP4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 14982 kb/s, 0.02 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 60k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16T13:18:14.000000Z
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16T13:18:14.000000Z
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000066703980] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000066703980] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000005b440c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
frame=268936 fps=1647 q=-1.0 Lsize= 8282945kB time=01:14:46.73 bitrate=15123.2kbits/s speed=27.5x    
video:8205691kB audio:70105kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.086390%
```

Running `ffmpeg -i` on one raw file produces the following output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/media/102GOPRO/GOPR0333.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-16 13:18:14
  Duration: 00:19:53.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15122 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14982 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16 13:18:14
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16 13:18:14
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16 13:18:14
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
```

Comment: Should be fine if the videos are exactly the same in terms of encoder settings. The duration mismatch can come from ffmpeg incorrectly estimating the complete duration. Do you see any glitches at the split points?

Comment: @slhck I don't see any glitches at the split points. The difference is 2s.

Comment: @slhck Are the warnings I'm getting also fine? I mean "Could not find codec parameters for stream 2" and "Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options" and "Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter"

Comment: The auto-inserted filter is correct. About the unknown stream, do you know if there's any stream you're expecting? What is shown when you open a single video file with `ffmpeg -i …`?

Comment: @slhck I only have on video stream and one audio stream I except. I have edited my post with the ffmpeg -i command of one video file. Do you think it is fine?

Comment: I think it's fine. You're losing a time code track which may be useful to have but definitely not required. Note that now I see a different, very old ffmpeg version in the header.

Comment: @slhck Yeah, the first one I have run on Win 7 with newest version of ffmpeg, the second one I have run on Ubuntu 16.04 with an old version. For concatenating I'm using the new version. What is the time code track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration difference may be a wrong overall estimation due to the individual tracks' timestamps. If you don't see any glitches at the individual videos' boundaries, you should be fine.

The information about the “MP4 to Annex B” filter is not a warning; you can ignore it.

Finally, it seems like there is a timecode track in the original files that is lost when concatenating the videos. This is not an issue if you don't plan on doing something with that timecode. That timecode may come in useful if you want to sync multiple GoPro recordings of the same event.